# Asking questions considering development of Ubuntu

Tags: support

Specifically in this case, I am tempted to ask a question regarding any continuing (non-supported by Canonical ) development of Unity (following [this](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/04/05/growing-ubuntu-for-cloud-and-iot-rather-than-phone-and-convergence)), largely with regard to licenses, [source code](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8) and other efforts which could perhaps make this a more community driven effort.

I would obviously avoid trying to make it a programming question (don't need to ;-) ), but would it be too broad or not accepted in another way?

Comment: If you think there's a userbase, there's nothing stopping you.  I do wonder what exactly one could ask about continuing to develop against the Unity codebase, but I don't see a reason to close it based on general questions that come to mind which aren't bugs.  In that vein though, I can't think of a lot of good questions.  Conversely, "I agree with the spirit of the question" has halted closevotes [before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115257/is-there-a-congrats-ubuntu-page)

Comment: @RobotHumans I think (please correct me if I'm wrong, Wilf) that the question is more about whether any non-Canonical continuation of unity would be on topic here rather than about any specific issues encountered while developing such a continuation.

Comment: If that's the question and not 100 other questions, I'm totally and completely on board with the question.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it depends on what you're asking really.  If @terdon is correct and it's as simple as a non-canonical maintained Unity question, I would consider it on-topic...  that's no different than someone saying "How do I install emacs?".

The problem we generally run in to is that the camel nose of bugs or programming questions tends to get under the edge of the tent.

Generally I like the idea, but I do see bug questions getting close vote hammers and people getting upset if it becomes a thing.